# Cloth flag not falling

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I'm creating a scene with 30 flags (in three rows of 10 flags each). Each flag has a different size.

I created the first flag (scale 1), and I'm duplicating one by one and increasing the scale. The first ten flags have the "Cloth" effect working normally, however, for some reason, for the eleventh flag (in the second row), the Cloth effect is not working.

When I start the animation, it doesn't fall like the others, it only has a slight wobble, but it remains attached to the rod without falling with gravity, as if it were a rigid plane attached to the rod. I saw that this happens depending on the position where I place the flag. But I can't understand and solve this problem.

I did some research but didn't find the solution. I already checked if there were duplicate vertices, but there aren't.

Comment: Hello, please share your file (only keep the useful objects)

Comment: This is a physical simulation.. to scale. Maybe, in proportion to the size of the fabric, the vertices don't weigh enough? Just a thought.